# JQuery document onload and PHP echo

Tags: jquery

I have a question relating to a php page I am writing.
Basically I have the some php code that is embedded in the body tags of my html page. 
The php echoes a couple of divs. Now, when I put some jquery in the head section of the html page, and call $(document).ready(function() {...  will this be called after my embedded php has echoed all the divs?

Many thanks for your input, and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PHP is interpreted, HTML is built
2. HTML is sent to the browser
3. Browser receives HTML, starts rendering the page, loading images, css and js files
4. $(document).ready( defined function) is called

Comment: +1 for complete answer, also you can use the list on the editor instead of using the code highlighter.

Comment: Tnx, and yeah, I figured that out as well, too late for the original post but I changed it. Another lesson learned :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Javascript (and thus jQuery) runs after.

All the PHP code runs on the server before the page is sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick replies! Makes sense now. I was just unsure with php thrown into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Php echo is executed on the server, and the browser gets just html regardless of how it's produced. So yes, it will be called after.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $(document).ready(function(){...code to execute...}); will be called after the entire page has been loaded, including anything echoed by php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, I usually place my JavaScript before closing the body tag.  Reference: [Where to place JavaScript in a HTML file?](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)